# dpkt invalid tcpdump header error

Tags: python, parsing, pcap, libpcap

I am getting ValueError: Invalid tcpdump header error for below code. Any help appreciated

```
import dpkt

f = open('a.pcap')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

for ts, buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    ip = eth.data
    tcp = ip.data

if tcp.dport == 80 and len(tcp.data) > 0:
    http = dpkt.http.Request(tcp.data)
    print http.uri

f.close()
```

The Error is shown below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "malcap.py", line 6, in <module>
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dpkt/pcap.py", line 104, in __init__
raise ValueError, 'invalid tcpdump header'
ValueError: invalid tcpdump header
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the pcap file in any other tool (like Wireshark) to confirm that it's valid and not corrupt?

Comment: yes tried. it works with wireshark

Comment: "It works with Wireshark" doesn't mean "it's a pcap file"; it could, for example, be a pcap-ng file, which newer versions of libpcap can read, but older versions of libpcap, and hand-written code to read pcap files, can't.  In Wireshark, go to Statistics -> Summary and see what "Format:" says.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since I met with same error, here is issue analysis.

**Note: at the moment it looks like issue observed on MacOS only while on Linux tcpdump works as expected.**

1) `man tcpdump` refers to pcap format:

> [See pcap-savefile(5) for a description of the file format.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/tcpdump.1.html)

and if you open PCAP-SAVEFILE document you may see:

> the first field in the per-file header is a 4-byte magic number, with the value 0xa1b2c3d4

2) From pcap.py you may see next:

```
elif self.__fh.magic != TCPDUMP_MAGIC:
    raise ValueError, 'invalid tcpdump header'
```

3) Based on 1) and 2) we may be sure that file is not pcap.

Let's check with hexdump:

```
hexdump test1.pcap  0000000 0a 0d 0d 0a
```

that's different from our expectations.

Let's check if this is a new format "pcap-ng". 
From http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html we may read next:

> Block Type: The block type of the Section Header Block is the integer
>   corresponding to the 4-char string "\r\n\n\r" (0x0A0D0D0A).

- that's what we want!

4) Since we are working with pylibpcap and there is no support for pcap-ng (at the moment) we need to deal with this issue somehow.

There are two options:
4.1) use editcap tool:

```
editcap -F libpcap -T ether test.pcapng test.pcap
```

4.2) gather data with dumpcap tool which supports data storage in both formats (use -P for old format). I.e.:

```
dumpcap -P -i en0 -w test.pcap
```

(en0 for macbook air case)

**However looks like there is a bug in Apple tcpdump implementation.**

Mac OS description for tcpdump says next:

> ```
>    -P     Use the pcap-ng file format when saving files.  Apple modification.
> ```

If you run tcpdump (without -P and without specifying -i interface):

```
tcpdump -w test.pcap
hexdump test.pcap
```

you will see result in pcap-ng format:

```
bash-3.2$ hexdump test.pcap  0000000 0a 0d 0d 0a
```

While if you run tcpdump with specified interface:

```
tcpdump -w test.pcap -i en0
```

Format would be correct:

```
bash-3.2$ hexdump test.pcap  0000000 d4 c3 b2 a1 02
```

Comment: The Mavericks tcpdump man page also speaks of using pcap-ng for "pktap" pseudo-interfaces and of, by default, capturing on "a set of interfaces defined by the kernel".  Unfortunately, it does *not* bother to tell you that this means that, by default, it captures on a pktap pseudo-interface and therefore it writes out a pcap-ng file by default.  (I.e., the bug is in the documentation, not the code.)

Comment: Hmm, even specifying the interface, I'm still getting `pcap-ng`. Also, not sure where to find either `editcap` or `dumpcap` tools - any help?

Comment: @dwanderson Both tools come packaged with wireshark.

Comment: I'm getting this error randomly on random PCAP whiles when reading from list of PCAP files.